# How to make an output of a function into a matrix

Tags: r, time, integer, markov

I'm quite new to R so this is a problem that I am encountering as a problem.

I currently using a Markov Chain from the 1st iteration to the 45th. I need to use the subsequent n and n+1 iteration in a function like this:

```css
bk<-function(n)((B[(n+1)]-B[n])/(B[n]-0.1818182))
```

However, I need it such that it only computes it so that N is only and ONLY an integer. I tried using a for loop but it does not seem to work properly.

```css
for (n in 0:45){
  bk<-function(n)(B[(n+1)]-B[n])/(B[n]-0.1818182)
  if(bk=0)
    next
  print(bk)
  }
```

The for loop tells me that "Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"

**(What I want is the function to compute N, IFF N is an integer. When N is not an integer the resulting value is 0, and that is why I am using a for loop to eliminate such values)**

This is what B is

```css
B
 [1] 1.0000000 0.8000000 0.6600000 0.5560000 0.4764000 0.4145600 0.3661360 0.3280400 0.2979758 0.2741956 0.2553518
[12] 0.2403975 0.2285151 0.2190636 0.2115391 0.2055441 0.2007647 0.1969524 0.1939101 0.1914812 0.1895416 0.1879922
[23] 0.1867542 0.1857649 0.1849741 0.1843419 0.1838365 0.1834324 0.1831093 0.1828509 0.1826442 0.1824789 0.1823467
[34] 0.1822409 0.1821564 0.1820887 0.1820346 0.1819913 0.1819567 0.1819290 0.1819068 0.1818891 0.1818749 0.1818636
[45] 0.1818545 0.1818472
> 

##Where B Comes from 
B<-c(intialstate1[,2])
```

The Markov Chain was made using the Markov Chain Package

```css
MCMolFrac<-new("markovchain",
               states=c("B","C","D","E"),
               transitionMatrix=matrix(data=c(0.8,0.2,0,0,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.1,0,0.2,0.8,0,0,0.4,0,0.6),byrow =TRUE,ncol=4), 
               name= "Unimolecular Reaction Distribution")
               
initialstate<-c(1,0,0,0)

fvals<-function(mchain,initialstate,n) {
  out<-data.frame()
    names(initialstate)<-names(mchain)
    for (i in 0:n)
     {
      iteration<-initialstate*mchain^(i)
      out<-rbind(out,iteration)
      }
  t<-cbind(out, i=seq(0,n))
  out<-out[,c(4,1:3)]
 return(out)
  }
  
  intialstate1<-data.frame(fvals(mchain = MCMolFrac, initialstate= c(1,0,0,0),n=45))
  
  ##leadingtoVectorBformationAbove
```

Essentially, I need to create a discrete time dynamical system. Such that I can make the output into a matrix/vector so I can graph it to look something like

[Graph of Final Product, the different colours are different datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6GO.png)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: In particular, please do not provide either your code or your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again.  Instead, paste your code into the question and for data use `dput` to get a text version that you can paste into the question.

Comment: Please, provide some code (in the right way). Thank you.

Comment: 1) Don't define the function `bk`inside the loop. 2) You must actually call the function, which you are not doing. 3) The `if` is comparing a **function** with `0`, not the function's return value (that doesn't even exist, see point 2). 4) The function `bk` is not defined for `n == 0`. 5) Try `for(n in 1:45){b <- bk(n); if(b != 0) print(b)}`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas that worked! Thank you so much!!